# Describe all the cyclic codes of length $7$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, coding-theory

$V^7$ is the set of length $7$ codewords. $V^7[x] = \mathbb F_2[x]/ \langle x^7-1\rangle $.

I know that each of these cyclic codes is constructed from a canonical generator (divisor of $x^7-1$).

So here's my set of divisors:

$$D=\{x^7-1,\; 1,\; 1+x,\; 1+x+x^3,\; 1 +x^2+x^3,\; (1+x)(1+x+x^3),\; (1+x)(1+x^2+x^3),\; (1+x+x^3)(1+x^2+x^3)\}$$

Each of these generates a different cyclic code of length $7$.

And I know that $\langle x^7-1 \rangle$ will correspond to the word $0000000$, since we always mod by $x^7-1$ after multiplying the elements of $V^7[x]$ by $x^7-1$.

Also $\langle 1 \rangle$ will just give $V^7$ since we multiply by $1$ then mod $x^7-1$ for each element in $V^7[x]$.

But what about the other ones? I don't see an obvious way of describing them without manually computing the ideals (which definitely is not the efficient way of solving this).

Comment: Can you identify a Hamming code among them? Its dual? Its bit-order reversed version? The dual of that? Actually the Hamming code is in its cyclic bit order, so I should talk about **a** Hamming code instead of using the definite article. The code with degree six generator you really just want to compute the ideal, if you don't see it right away. The code with the linear generator also. Hint: a polynomial is divisible by $x+1$, iff its weight is ____?

Comment: Even? I'm not sure. Why is your hint true?

Comment: Correct. A polynomial is divisible by $x+1$ if and only if $-1$ is its zero. Here $-1=1$.

Comment: Yes but what does this have to do with the weight?

Comment: The words of an even weight form a linear code. That code also happens to be cyclic (not hard to show). More is true: If the generator $g(x)$ of a binary cyclic code $C$ has an odd weight, then the polynomial $g(x)(x+1)$ generates the subcode of $C$ consisting of the even weight words of $C$.

Comment: What's $V^5$ and what does it have to do with cyclic codes of length $7$?

Comment: @DilipSarwate, sorry that is a typo, I corrected it.