# Number of (binary) cyclic codes of length 21

Tags: abstract-algebra, coding-theory

what are all the binary cyclic codes of length $21$? Is it possible to find all values of k for which $[21,k]$ is a binary cyclic code? 
How do i go about this problem, does finding the cyclotomic cosets have something to do with the solution? I looked at [Describe all the cyclic codes of length $7$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/776625/describe-all-the-cyclic-codes-of-length-7) but it really does not help much. thanks alot.

Comment: Appendix D of Peterson and Weldon's 1972 book _Error-correcting Codes_ lists the dimension, minimum distance, distance guaranteed by the BCH bound, and roots of generator polynomial of _all_ the cyclic binary codes of (odd) lengths up to $65$. You can check your answers against this table.

Comment: ok thanks, but i got it really. We, in short, basically have a 2 from each polynomial. so $2^6 == 64$. right?

Comment: Yes, $2^6 = 64$ because you can choose to include or exclude each of the six factors from your generator polynomial. Also, read the answer you have accepted again; I just corrected a small error in it regarding $k$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hm... If you did not find that answer helpful (it tells you exactly how to find all such codes if you replace 7 with 21) I am not sure what could possibly help. Maybe repetition? Let's try.

The number of cyclic binary codes of length n corresponds to ideals of $F_2[x]/(x^n-1)$, and those correspond to divisors of $x^n-1$.

A factorization into irreducibles is $x^{21}-1=(1+x)(1+x+x^2)(1+x^2+x^3)(1+x+x^3)(1+x^2+x^4+x^5+x^6)(1+x+x^2+x^4+x^6),$ and that gives you all 64 divisors.

You did not mention what $k$ is supposed to be, but I guess it is the dimension of the code. This is simply $21$ *minus*
the degree of the chosen generator polynomial (more generally, the
generator polynomial is of degree $n-k$ where $n$ is the block length), and I'll let you puzzle out what the possibilities are.

Cyclotomic cosets would be helpful for factoring by hand. Including the details of that would exceed the scope of this post.

Comment: ahh, this is just enough thanks :). I understand but what makes them 64 in total? I can see only 6 of them.

Comment: ahh, it is ok. i got it :)

Comment: I corrected a minor error in your answer. Feel free to roll back if you disagree with the changes I made.

Comment: @DilipSarwate You're right: I had forgotten about this feature. It's been a few years since I thought about this. Thanks for helping!

Comment: @rschwieb How do we choose an approriate generator polynomial so that we find the right dimension?

Comment: @rschwieb Do we pick a polynomial by looking at its degree?

Comment: @Evinda yes, the degree of the polynomial determines the dimension of the code