# ternary cyclic codes of length 27

Tags: coding-theory

With $k = 1,2,3,\ldots,26$, is it possible to find a ternary cyclic code of length $27$ and dimension $k$? How can i show that it exists - if it does?

Comment: In $k = 1,2,3...26$ versus $k = 1,2,3,\ldots,26$, there's a reason why the dots appear closer together in the first item. I changed it to standard usage.

Comment: oh, wow. what might that be o.O ? i had no idea.

Comment: Although this is about codes over $\mathbb F_3$ instead of over $\mathbb F_2$ (and of course there is the unfortunate typo -- I am sure the OP's homework calls for codes of length $26 = 3^3-1$ instead of length $27$), there is very little difference between this question and the [OP's previous question about cyclic binary codes of length $21$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1306584/15941).

Comment: Hint: $x^{26}-1$ is the product of two polynomials of degree $1$ and eight polynomials of degree $3$. Figure out why this must be so and you are done. If you really meant $27$, @Jyrki has already answered you.

Comment: Yes, he did, but it is after this hint that his answer now makes a lot of sense :)

Comment: I share Dilip's suspicion that 26 is a more natural length for a cyclic ternary code. 27 is a rather degenerate case - see my answer for a reason. It is not impossible that the exercise does call for length 27 codes, just a bit unusual :-)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen The interesting thing is that _all_ $k$ from $0$ to $26$ are achievable for $n=26$ just as they are for $n=27$. In the OP's [other question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1306584/15941) about cyclic binary codes of length $21$, not all $k$ are possible.

Comment: Why didn't I see that, Dilip? We have two ones and plenty of threes :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Over the field $GF(3)$ we have
$$
p(x)=x^{27}-1=(x-1)^{27}
$$
by the so called *freshman's dream* (check this if you don't see it right away). Recall that a degree $t$ factor of $p(x)$ generates a code of dimension $k=27-t$.

Comment: thanks. This is now very clear. Thanks to Dilip's comment as well.